# Reduce an array of object with same key and concat same property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in the  below form it has three properties serviceName, pool, and environment I want to group the object based on environment and at the same time need to concat the pools:

```
const data = [
  {
    serviceName: "visa",
    pool: "3g",
    environment: "test-int",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "visa",
    pool: "4g",
    environment: "test-int",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "visa",
    pool: "5g",
    environment: "test-int",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "amex",
    pool: "5g",
    environment: "dev",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "amex",
    pool: "6g",
    environment: "dev",
  },
];
```

I want the output in the below format:

```
const output = [
    {
      serviceName: "visa",
      pool: "3g,4g,5g",
      environment: "test-int"
    },
    {
      serviceName: "amex",
      pool: "5g,6g",
      environment: "dev"
    },
  ]
```

Based on my current code it just returns a single object instead of an array of objects:

```
const output = data.reduce((acc, ar) => {
      let res = {
        ...acc,
        pool: acc["pool"] + "," + ar.pool
      };
      return res;
    }
  });
```

Comment: What's not working here?  Did you get console errors?  Is this in a browser or backend?  Please clarify where you are having problems.

Comment: @mrrogers i just joined StackOverflow so was figuring out how to format the code i have added the required details

Comment: `pool` is probably more useful as an array instead of a string. Also `reduce()` returns a single result as you've already experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that you need to segment out all the elements that match by `serviceName` and *then* do your reduce to join the `pool` value.

Maybe something like this:

```js
const res = [
    {
      serviceName: "visa",
      pool: "3g",
      environment: "test-int"
    },
    {
      serviceName: "visa",
      pool: "4g",
      environment: "test-int"
    },
    {
      serviceName: "amex",
      pool: "5g",
      environment: "dev"
    },
    {
      serviceName: "amex",
      pool: "6g",
      environment: "dev"
    }
  ];

const groupBy = (arr, getKey) => {
  return arr.reduce((memo, item) => {
    const key = getKey(item)
    memo[key] ||= [];
    memo[key].push(item);
    return memo;
    
  }, {})
}

const byServiceName = groupBy(res, ({serviceName}) => serviceName);

const results = Object.values(byServiceName).map((items) => {
   return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
     let res = {
        ...acc,
        pool: acc["pool"] + "," + item.pool
      };
      return res;
    })
});

console.log(results)
```

The `groupBy` function could be simplified to not take the `getKey` function, but that adds a little flexibility.  If you know it's always going to be on serviceName, you could instead have something like

```js
const groupByServiceName = (arr) => {
  const key = 'serviceName'
  return arr.reduce((memo, item) => {
    memo[key] ||= [];
    memo[key].push(item);
    return memo;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that generates an object with `environment` value as key and then extracts its values into array

```js
const data = [
  {
    serviceName: "visa",
    pool: "3g",
    environment: "test-int",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "visa",
    pool: "4g",
    environment: "test-int",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "visa",
    pool: "5g",
    environment: "test-int",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "amex",
    pool: "5g",
    environment: "dev",
  },
  {
    serviceName: "amex",
    pool: "6g",
    environment: "dev",
  },
];

const output = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, ar) =>
{
  if (acc[ar.environment])
    acc[ar.environment].pool += "," + ar.pool;
  else
    acc[ar.environment] = {...ar};

  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Interesting.  Same as my solution except keyed by `environment`.  I guess it's not clear, @giiyiraj, which thing is the "grouping" criteria.  I assumed it was `serviceName` but I guess it could be either... or both.

Comment: The problem statement is "Given a list of services I want to group the services deployed based on environments and add the pools so basically as we see between the two same services the field that's different is the pool so wanted to reduce it to a single field instead of displaying multiple records in the UI"